# How to save a series of jpegs to click through?

Tags: presentation

I have a series of pictures (jpeg or other format), and want to save them and then send them to another person, such that the person can click through them, since the pictures tell a story :-)
How is that possible to achieve?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some sort of presentation, not photography.

Comment: I would challenge that display of photos is part of photography.  Presentation is ambiguous according to the FAQ (not specifically mentioned in either category) but I would argue it's part of photography.  There is some previous discussion about related topics on [meta](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3975/questions-about-presentation-of-panoramic-photos).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with any gallery.  You can either do it with an online gallery that you can send them a link to or they could simply view it in a gallery program.  Windows includes a built in gallery viewer that will let someone walk through the photos in a folder in order for example.  You could also make a video out of them, though this would take considerably more space.

Another approach would be to use some program with a publicly available viewer.  For example, if you have Powerpoint, you could put them in to a Powerpoint presentation and there is a free Powerpoint Viewer for Windows machines at least.  That's not the only option, but there are far too many possible options to enumerate.

Comment: What can of online galleries are available? Would love to send just a link to the other person. I have searched and not found anything suitable. Dont want a video though

Comment: Don't forget the comic book formats, CBR and CBZ. They're just RARs (CBR) or ZIPs (CBZ) of images numbered in the order of display, and there are a number of comic book readers out there that will display them as books (complete with front and back covers if you want).

Comment: that's exactly what I have been looking for, thank you!!

Comment: @Pegah - I'd think just about any online photo sharing site should support moving through a gallery with a next button.  You can take your pick.  Facebook, 500px, Smugmug, whatever.  There are literally dozens, if not hundreds of options.  Personally I always post them to my own site either in Wordpress, ownCloud or a Flash or HTML gallery produced out of Lightroom.